# HTML - PHP : Disable a form field once data has been inserted into a field

Tags: php, html, forms

I am not even sure if it is possible. I have a form that inserts data successfully in a db, then echo's the information back out using sessions. Is it possible that once the information is echo'd out one of the form fields within the form can be made disabled, so the information cannot be edited.

or is this to far fetched?

Comment: You can add `disabled` at the end of your field to disable it. If you generate those field using PHP, than add that at the end of the tag. Otherwise, add inline PHP like this `<?php ECHO ($SESSION['SOMETHING] ? 'disabled' : '') ?>`. The very best, of course, is not to mix PHP and HTML and, instead use template engine like Smarty to achieve a good MVC model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You just need to check if the session is set.

Let me show an example.

Let's say you have:

```
$_SESSION['User']['email'] = "testemail@gmail.com";

<?php $disabled = (isset($_SESSION['User']['email'])) ? "disabled" : ""; ?>
```

Now the HTML:

```
 <input type="email" value='<?php echo $_SESSION['User']['email'] ?>' <?php echo $disabled ?>>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if i had $_SESSION['fran_email'] = $upda_dets['Franchise_email']; i would then define $disabled = (isset($_SESSION['fran_email'])) ? "disabled" : "";  and then put both in the HTML.    Just want to ensure i doing this right

Comment: It means if the session is present, $disabled will be = "disabled", and if not, $disabled will be blank.

Comment: Thats my problem. The form field populated with data just not disabled. So i just wanted to see if i had understood properly

Comment: It's supposed to work just fine. Have you put any other if condition apart from the one I've mentioned? Please specify in case you have.

Comment: I have a number of sessions defined, but apart from that no